# Angular service HTTP dependancy injection does not return anything

Tags: angular

I am trying to call a service `MachineLearningService`  from my helper function. The service is supposed to receive arguments and return a response from an api. After adding the http dependency in my constructor, i can't see anything in the console neither do i get a response, if i remove the http dependacy, im able to return mock data. Any ideas/links to what i might be doing wrong will be appreciated.

My helper function code

```
@Injectable()
export class JsExpressionHelper {
  // constructor() {}
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  evaluateML(...args) {
    const htsDataSource = new MachineLearningService(this.http);
    console.log("---here", htsDataSource.getHTSRiskScore(args))

    //return htsDataSource.getHTSRiskScore(args);
    return htsDataSource.getHTSRiskScore(args).subscribe(resp => {return resp})
  }

  get helperFunctions() {
    const helper = this;
    return {
      evaluateML: helper.evaluateML
    };
  }
}
```

My service code

```
@Injectable()
export class MachineLearningService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public getHTSRiskScore(params) {
    let predictionVariables = {
      AgeAtTest: params.age,
      MonthsSinceLastTest: params.monthsSinceLastTestInt > 0 ? params.monthsSinceLastTestInt : 0,
      GenderMale: params.gender == 'M' ? 1 : 0,
      GenderFemale: params.gender == 'F' ? 1 : 0,
      KeyPopulationTypeGP: 0,
      KeyPopulationTypeSW: 0
    };

    const headers = { 'content-type': 'application/json' }
    const url = 'http://1.1.1.1:8600/openmrs/ws/rest/v1/keml/casefindingscore';
    return this.http.post(`${url}`, predictionVariables, { 'headers': headers });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inject the MachineLearningServicein your JsExpressionHelper service

```
constructor(private machineLearningService: MachineLearningService) { }

evaluateML(...args) {
return this.machineLearningService.getHTSRiskScore(args).pipe(
   tap(value => console.log(value) // to be removed
);
```

}

Comment: Unfortunately, it still seems like service is not being called

Comment: did you subscribe to evalueatML()?

Comment: yes, i can see the ```args``` when i log them

Comment: can you provide a small stackblitz example?

Comment: At the point that the service was invoked, this.machineLearningService was undefined because the evaluateML function isn’t properly bound to the Helper instance (so this at the point it’s run is the object returned from the helperFunctions getter.